# Compiling GUI from source differences by OS

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, linux, windows, macos, compile

Has there been a stated reason why instructions to compile the new GUI from source are currently available for Linux and OSX but not Windows? Since Windows users have been most vocal about their desire for a GUI I would like to understand the reason (if any) for the current prioritization of the developers working on the GUI.

https://github.com/mbg033/monero-core#compiling-monero-core-from-source

https://github.com/monero-project/monero-core#compiling-monero-core-from-source

Are compiling instructions more difficult to create for Windows?

Is testing needed more for Linux and OSX than for Windows?

What other reasons can explain the current prioritization?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no publicly available reason as far as I know, but compiling on Windows is usually a bit more difficult to compiling on OSX and certainly on Linux. However, Ilya Kitaev has provided Windows build instructions in one of his branches. The instructions have, at the time of writing, not been PRed to master yet. The Windows compile instructions can be found [here](https://github.com/mbg033/monero-core/blob/9d79fdbeed31a7600c713ec80d98d6f507b5ee81/README.md#on-windows). The instructions are as follows:

> #### On Windows:
>
> 1. Install [msys2](http://msys2.github.io/), follow the instructions on that page on how to update packages to the latest versions
> 2. Install monero dependencies as described in [monero documentation](https://github.com/monero-project/monero)
> 3. Install git:
>
>    `pacman -S git`
> 4. Install Qt5:
>
>    - if you need to build x86 application, install:
>
>      `pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-qt5`
>    - if you need to build x64 application, install:
>
>      `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-qt5`
> 5. Open `mingw` shell. MSYS2 will install start menu items for both mingw32 and mingw64 environments, so    you need to open
>      appropriate one:    `%MSYS_ROOT%\msys2_shell.cmd -mingw32` for x86
>      targed    or     `%MSYS_ROOT%\msys2_shell.cmd -mingw64` for x64
>      targed
>
>    Where `%MSYS_ROOT%` will be `c:\msys32` if your host OS is
>      x86-based or `c:\msys64` if your host OS    is x64-based
> 6. Clone git repository:
>      
>      `git clone https://github.com/monero-project/monero-core.git`
> 7. Build the project:
>      
>      `cd monero-core
>      ./build.sh`
> 8. Take result binary and dependencies in `./build/release/bin`
>
>    **important: if you testing application within VirtualBox virtual
>      machine, make sure 3D acceleration is enabled    in machine's
>      settings:    Machine > Settings > Display > [v] Enable 3D
>      Acceleration**