# GUI pull request to build and install monerod

Tags: development, monero-wallet-gui, build

Until now users wishing to test the upcoming GUI had to build from [source](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2346/compiling-gui-from-source-differences-by-os). Following these Monero development [stalker instructions](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2935/following-coding-progress-between-dev-meetings), I just noticed a new [pull request](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-core/pull/256) which excited me.

Some relevant [lines](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-core/pull/256/files#diff-0b83f9dedf40d7356e5ca147a077acb4R13) provide clues to its meaning:

> +MONEROD_EXEC=monerod
>
> +# Build libwallet if monero folder doesnt exist

There are also some [32bit](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-core/pull/256/files#diff-f179023e5f60c20d4f9f851689fdedffR80) specific lines:

> +# Build monerod
>
> +# win32 need to build daemon manually with msys2 toolchain

Does the above mean that soon the GUI will not require manually compiling monerod from source (with a win32 exception)? Is this pull request is indicative of something very late in the (pre-release) development lifecycle?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GUI daemon manager is recently merged into monero-core. I.e you can start/stop local daemon from GUI. This PR basically means that monerod is getting built when you build the GUI. Unfortunately win32 still requires some manual work.